# Hyper Link inside html select control

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a html select control. I want to have a item which is a link to navigate to some other page, when it is selected with out postbacking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ?

```
<select onchange="location=this.options [this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>- Select -</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com" >Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com" >Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com" >Stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. But only one selected option should navigate to particular page. Since other options have some other values.

Comment: @S.Siva I'm not clear what you said. Can you provide me your html code sample ?

Comment: I have 3 options in the select control which is used to search operation. If I click the first option, it has to navigate to URL. If I click other two options, it should postback and navigate to results page.

Comment: I think, I can use the same code, by checking the option label value. If the label value is 'Facebook' the I can set the locations to selectedIndex value. Am I correct?